# send keys using a condition python

Tags: python, pandas, key

I want to create a loop through which, I send as keys,each value of column A and once value is sent, I send as keys the value from the correspondent row in column B then continue with next value in column A and so on.I column B I may have more then a value on row, separated by space

```
ID = df['A'] .to_list()
for l in ID:
    myElement.send_keys(l)  ## this will send as keys, value from column A
```

Next thing will be to send as keys the correspondent value(same row) in column B for each l in column A.

Is there a way to create this condition?

[image]

Considering the example df, steps should be send value1 then cavo, then lampada. Send value2, then cavo, then lampada

Comment: can you give an example with your data?

Comment: Instead of converting the column to a list, why don't you use `df.iterrows()`?

Comment: I still don't get the question. @Barmar can you tell me what OP tried to ask?

Comment: @devReddit  done

Comment: I think he just wants to send `value1`, then `cavo lampada`, then `value2`, then `cavo lampada`

Comment: @Barmar actually send value1 then cavo, then lampada.Send value2, then cavo, then lampada

Comment: Put that clarification in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertuples()`. Then you can access each column that you want to send in the loop.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    for word in row.A.split():
        myElement.send_keys(word)
    for word in row.B.split():
        myElement.send_keys(word)
```